# I am trying to add an event handler that adds a location record to an event table with an SQL command(stored procedure)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

```
private void btnEventLocationAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _eventLocation = new Location();

    string locationName = txtBoxLocationName.Text;
    string address = txtBoxStreet.Text + ", " + txtBoxCity.Text + ", " + txtBoxState.Text;
    string eventName = txtBoxEventName.Text;
    string eventDescription = txtBoxEventDescription.Text;
```

It first checks to see if the location record exists in the database(first line in the try). I get the error here because if the location is null it cannot call the method as the method requires non null parameters. how could I bypass this?

```
try
{
    _eventLocation = _locationManager.RetrieveLocationByNameAndAddress(locationName, address);
    if(_eventLocation.LocationName is null)
    {
        _locationManager.CreateLocation(locationName, address);
        _eventLocation = _locationManager.RetrieveLocationByNameAndAddress(locationName, address);
    }

    _eventManager.CreateEvent(eventName, eventDescription, _eventLocation.LocationID);

    MessageBox.Show("Event Added");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is "the location". What is "the method" you are referring to? What is the exception?

Comment: Please don't delete [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959173/i-am-trying-to-add-an-event-handler-that-checks-to-see-if-a-location-object-exis) and just repost it.  That's a quick way to get a question ban.

Comment: It seems just a check on the _locationname_ and _address_ variables using _string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace_

Comment: the location is a data object with values that exist in a database. The event is also a data object, the event table has a locationID foreign key and cannot exist without a location record. When I call the RetrieveLocationByNameAndAddress method passing it a location object that doesnt exist it returns a null location object.

Comment: When I try the createEvent method passing it the null locationID I get a System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'. Since the createEvent method requires a locationID that is 6 digits

Comment: It sounds like your location manager has some problems. That aside, just check for null before calling the method and if it is null, don't call it.

Comment: @Dixie_normous can you edit your question to include the implementation of `RetrieveLocationByNameAndAddress` and `CreateLocation`?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is you are getting back null when you first call `RetrieveLocationByNameAndAddress` then you may want to try checking for null on the `_eventLocation` object and not on the `_eventLocation.LocationName` property.

```
try
{
    _eventLocation = _locationManager.RetrieveLocationByNameAndAddress(locationName, address);
    // check for null on the '_eventLocation' object as if it's null then you will not have a LocationName property
    if(_eventLocation == null)
    {
        _locationManager.CreateLocation(locationName, address);
        _eventLocation = _locationManager.RetrieveLocationByNameAndAddress(locationName, address);
    }
    _eventManager.CreateEvent(eventName, eventDescription, _eventLocation.LocationID);
    MessageBox.Show("Event Added");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: The issue is the second time I call the retrieve the database doesnt  refresh, after the exception is called I looked in the location table and sure enough its there. And I know the retreive method works because I modified the handler to test the retrieve method with data that I know is already in the table and it returns the correct location that way.

Comment: After creating a new location and then trying to retrieve the new location is when I get the null object.